# TSQL: Dynamically build query string

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, case, where-clause

I have some trouble creating a dynamic `Where` clause.

I would like to pass in a parameter to a function, and then use that parameter to retrieve values from the database and use that in my `Where` clause, and then return a resulting value.

I've tried numerous options, but my best try so far is:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetID (@TaskID varchar(10))
                RETURNS Int
AS  
BEGIN
  DECLARE @TaskType varchar(10)
  DECLARE @TaskSubType TinyInt
  DECLARE @ID Int
  DECLARE @SQL varchar(400) 

  SELECT @TaskType = TaskType, @TaskSubType = TaskSubType
  FROM Tasks
  WHERE TaskID = @TaskID

  SET @SQL = 'SELECT @ID = ID
              FROM ZCircuitFaults
              WHERE TaskType = @TaskType AND ' + 
                    CASE WHEN ISNULL(@TaskSubType, '') <> ''
                         THEN '(TaskSubType Is Null OR TaskSubType = CAST(@TaskSubType AS Varchar))'
                    ELSE 'TaskSubType Is Null'
                    END
exec sp_executesql @SQL
                 , N'@ID Int, @TaskType varchar(10), @TaskSubType tinyint'
                 , @ID, @TaskType, @TaskSubType
                 , @ID = @ID OUTPUT
RETURN @ID
END
```

When I call:

```
PRINT dbo.GetID('ABC123')
```

I get the error:

> Only functions and some extended stored procedures can be executed from within a function.

Comment: Try doing it in a stored procedure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is that you cannot use dynamic SQL from within a function and you can't call stored procedures as well. With that solution is, convert your function to a stored procedure.

Also, I don't see why you need a dynamic SQL. Your dynamic SQL part can just be

```
SELECT @ID = ID
              FROM ZCircuitFaults
              WHERE TaskType = @TaskType AND 
                    CASE WHEN ISNULL(@TaskSubType, '') <> ''
                         THEN (TaskSubType Is Null OR TaskSubType = CAST(@TaskSubType AS Varchar))
                    ELSE TaskSubType Is Null
                    END
```

and then

```
RETURN @ID;
```

**EDIT:**

Your entire `WHERE` part can be simplified to below

```
WHERE TaskType = @TaskType 
AND (
TaskSubType Is Null 
OR 
TaskSubType = ISNULL(CAST(@TaskSubType AS Varchar), '')
)
```

Comment: Thanks.  The SQL you proposed is where I started off with, but you can't use a case statement like that in a Where clause.  There are a couple of posts on work-arounds.  In this instance I get an 'Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Is' at the THEN part.

Comment: @user1208908, Yes, it's correct. Didn't notice that you are not referencing a column in `WHERE` condition; but you know you actually don't need a `case` condition at all. Your entire `WHERE` can be simplified to what I have in edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

Per books online, you cannot use dynamic SQL inside a function:

> User-defined functions cannot make use of dynamic SQL or temp tables.
>   Table variables are allowed.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191320.aspx *Limitations and Restrictions* section. You will need to put this into a stored procedure.

---

@Rahul is right, you don't need dynamic SQL.